# Django ссылаться на одно view, независимо от наличия слэша

Tags: python, django

В Django приходят `callback` на один урл, то со слэшом, то без cлэша.

`./sub_callback/` и `./sub_callback`

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы на слэш django не обращало внимание и выполняло одно `view`, кроме случая когда надо писать 2 записи в `urls.py`

`APPEND_SLASH=TRUE` -  отключал, но так работает только один урл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы записывать путь один раз. Для этого используется `re_path` вместо `path`

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  re_path(r'^sub_callback/?$', views.view_name),
]
```